# getting nothing from lookup mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get all the posts with their author details from user model. I am using mongoDB lookup. But getting an empty array. I am matching author.uid from post to _id of user.
I want to get all the posts with their author details from user model. I am using mongoDB lookup. But getting an empty array. I am matching author.uid from post to _id of user.
//Post Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
category : {
    type: String
},
content: {
    type: String
},
caption: {
    type: String
},
tags: [{
    type: String
}],
createdAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
 author: {
    uid:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    }
},
likes:[{
    type:String
}],

comments:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
}]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

//User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
avatar:{
    type:String
},
bio:{
    type: String
},
followers:[
    {
        type: String 
    }
],
followings:[
    {
        type: String
    }
],
posts:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post"
}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

//Node js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Post = require('../../models/Post');
const User = require('../../models/user');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: 'User',
                localField: "author.uid",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "creator"
            }
    }
]).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error" ,err)
    }
    if (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});    
});
```

//Output

```
 {"_id":"5b9c7f30d",
 "author": {"uid":"y08RxtsHe","name":"Sujoy Saha"},
 "tags": ["#lo"],
 "likes":[],  "comments[],

 "category":"image","content":"jsdnvs","caption":"standing 
 \n#lol","createdAt":1536982759517,"__v":0,"creator":[]}
```

You can see, i am getting empty creator array. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

mongoose.js pluralizes (adds 's' after your model name) when it creates a collection in MongoDb.

Can you try with `from: 'users'` in your $lookup clause?

Comment: Tried. Same result.

Comment: @Sujoy Are you sure you used `users`, not `Users`? Because it is case-sensitive.

Comment: I have changed it to 'users' and now its working. Now my question is why it is 'users' though i have used 'User' in other part of the code?

Comment: @Sujoy Good to hear that your code is working now. This is because, In $lookup clause, you need to specify a collection's name rather than a mongoose model name. And by default, when you define a model in mongoose, mongoose creates a collection with pluralized and lower cased name. FYI, mongoDB collection name is case-sensitive, but lower-case name is recommended.